# does else exist on datadog is_match

Tags: datadog

I am trying to set up slack monitors with datadog, based on the environment.
For e.g. if the environment is production got to slack channel A and if it is uat go to slack channel B and all other environments should go to slack channel C.

```
 message = <<EOF
{{#is_match "environment.name" "production"}}
   {{#is_alert}} @slack-datadog-production {{/is_alert}}
{{/is_match}}
{{#is_match "environment.name" "uat"}}
   {{#is_alert}} @slack-datadog-uat {{/is_alert}}
{{/is_match}}
else
  {{#is_alert}} @slack-datadog {{/is_alert}}
EOF
```

But I can't find a way to do the last part where all others should go to slack channel B. 
Looked at the documentation in https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/notifications and googled but couldn't find anything that can do an else condition.

Answer (score 6):

Starts to get messy, but you could nest two "does not" conditional variables, like this:

```
 message = <<EOF
{{#is_match "environment.name" "production"}}
   {{#is_alert}} @slack-datadog-production {{/is_alert}}
{{/is_match}}
{{#is_match "environment.name" "uat"}}
   {{#is_alert}} @slack-datadog-uat {{/is_alert}}
{{/is_match}}

{{^is_match "environment.name" "production"}}
   {{^is_match "environment.name" "uat"}}
      {{#is_alert}} @slack-datadog {{/is_alert}}
   {{/is_match}}
{{/is_match}}
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

You can actually just use:

```
EOF
@slack-datadog-{{environment.name}}
EOF
```

Datadog's monitor templating feature will fill in the blank and forward to the relevant channel as long as you whitelisted it in the integrations tile for Slack.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on the question. I actually wants to send all environments to 3 channels. i.e production to prosuction, uat to uat and all others to a single channel.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they updated to have `{{else}}` statements. See here https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/notify/variables/?tab=is_match#examples

```
{{#is_match "role.name" "db"}}
  This displays if the host triggering the alert contains `db`
  in the role name. @db-team@company.com
{{else}}
  This displays if the role tag doesn't contain `db`.
  @slack-example
{{/is_match}}
```

But I don't think it works like with multiple `is_match` statements like an if elif else chain.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).